# Add Text inside inverted Commas in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have got this text as one of the records.

'20320323,90239013,9438932'

I want to add inverted commas for each numbers present. 
So, I want to update this record as - 
'20320323','90239013','9438932'

Answer (score 0):

If your input is already quoted:

```
OReplace(col, ',', ''',''')
```

otherwise

```
''''||OReplace(col, ',', ''',''') || ''''
```

Why do you want to store a repeating group and why in such a way?
You might consider storing it as JSON for simplified querying.